# What's the best best practice to validate object fields?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

The below function has to validate the the required object fields before proceeding further. There is no strict requirement to return a generic validation error messages versus specific error message. What's the best practice to be followed?

Returning generic validation message,

```
function getAccountDetails({userId, accountId, email}) {
 if(!userId || !accountId || !email) {
   return 'userId or accountId or email is required';
 }
 // Todo

}
```

Returning specific validation error message,

```
 function getAccountDetails({userId, accountId, email}) {
  if(!userId) {
    return 'userId is required';
  }
  if(!accountId) {
    return 'accountId is required';
  }
  if(!email) {
    return 'email is required';
  }
  // Todo

}
```

Comment: I would `throw Error('some message');` instead of returning. Aside from that, it's impossible to say without knowing the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say none of them is best. as the function is expected to return the account details not the errors.

A good practice will be to throw the error and catch it on the other side using `try/catch` block.

```js
if(!userId || !accountId || !email) {
   throw Error("userId or accountId or email is required")
 }
```

between from both of the approaches ... do what suits you best or you think is best there is no any recommendation.

Comment: I like it. Returning the error is best in case of validation failure. Would it good to throw error with specific error message or generic?

Comment: whichever case is the best for you. like on front-end you have inputs and on error you want to add error class to those inputs (To make them redish on error). you can go with the second approach or if you are simply printing the error on page go for 1st method.